# 列挙型の２項演算子について

Tags: swift

詳解swiftで勉強しています。

プロトコルの定義のところで、Comparableプロトコルを列挙型に適合する場合、
実体型をもつ列挙型は、すでに「＝＝」をもっていますとあるのですが、

通常の列挙型（実体型ではない）は「＝＝」が使用できないように思えるのですが、
実際は使用できます。

この意味は、どう理解すべきでしょうか

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
enum CompassPoint {
    case North
    case South
    case East
    case West
}
```

上記のような、Assciated Valueを持たない単なるEnumはコンパイラによって自動的に`Equatable`になります。

> Simple enums that have no associated data (like MyBool) are automatically made Equatable by the compiler, so no additional code is required.
>   https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=8

そのため、`==`で比較する際には下記で定義されいている演算子が使用されます。

```
public func ==<T : Equatable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool
```

```
enum Barcode {
    case UPCA(Int, Int, Int, Int)
    case QRCode(String)
}
```

一方、上記のようなAssociated Valueを持つEnumはそうはならないので、自分で`==`を実装する必要があります。

> However, you can make arbitrary types equatable by conforming to the Equatable protocol and implementing the == operator.
>   https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=8

```
enum Math: Double {
    case Pi = 3.1415
    case Phi = 1.6180
    case Tau = 6.2831
}
```

上記のようなDoubleやStringを継承しているようなEnumで`==`による比較ができるのは`RawRepresentable`に適合するので、下記の演算子が使用されるためです。

```
func ==<T : RawRepresentable where T.RawValue : Equatable>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool
```